# Indentation before parentheses Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, format

Let us suppose that I have such code after formatting in Intellij Idea:

```
for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
{
  i = a;
}

while (x < 0)
{
  number = number + 1;
}

function f (a)
{
  return a;
}
```

How can I change settings so that the code was such after formatting:

```
for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
{
  i = a;
}

while(x < 0)
{
  number = number + 1;
}

function f(a)
{
  return a;
}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure it in the JavaScript code style settings, Spaces:

[image: code style]